# What is necessary to use Win32 extensions with Portable Python

Tags: python, portable-python

I installed Portable Python in an USB drive and it is working but I cannot make it import Win32 extensions.

Comment: not using `win32` extensions will make it portable

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you using? What is the error?

If you are using PP 1.1 based on 2.6.1, there is a known bug that prevents import of pythoncom and there is also a workaround to fix it:

http://groups.google.com/group/portablepython/browse_frm/thread/acfacb783bc39cb7